# How to append new ListView items at the top

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-listview

I am fetching `ListView.builder()` items from **Cloud Firestore** inside a `StreamBuilder`. I want the new item to be added at the top of the `ListView`. How can I do that? I tried `reverse : true` , though it reverse the `ListView`, but when there is only 2/3 items, the `ListView` looks ugly, as the `ListView` starts from bottom and the upper portion of the screen remains empty.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49062313/1367159) helps

Comment: @Sukhi My data are coming from firestore. Cant set the index manually.

Comment: can you just just add orderBy to the firebase query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added `shrinkWrap: true` and put the `ListView` inside an `Align` widget with `alignment: Alignment.topCenter` and got the result I wanted!

```
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  reverse: true,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  ...
                  ...
               )
             )
```

Answer (score 1):

- if you want to add new item at the top of the the listview and if you are
  using firestore used **Timestamp**

**firebase. firestore. Timestamp**

A Timestamp represents a point in time independent of any time zone

**use this method**

Timestamp.now()

**fetch data from firestore order by time using StreamBuilder**

```
  Widget item() =>
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    //fetch data from friends collection order by time
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection("friends").orderBy(
        "time", descending: true).snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      //if data not exist show loading indicator
      if (!snapshot.hasData)
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      //if data exist 
      return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data['name']);
      });
    },
  );
```

**add data in firestore**

```
 Firestore.collection("friends")
      .document(friends.otherUID)
      .setData({"name" : "xyz","time": Timestamp.now()});
```

- if you want to update item and you want to add updated item at the top of the listview

**update data**

```
     Future<void> updatefriends({String name,Timestamp time}) async {
Map<String, Object> updateFriend = Map();

if (name.isNotEmpty) updateFriend['name'] = name;
if (time !=null) updateFriend['time']=time;


Firestore.instance.collection("friends")
    .document(uid)
    .updateData(updateFriend);
```

}

Comment: That is a way to add a data to the FirestoreDb and then display, but not just add to the list (ads for example)...

Answer (score 1):

Just create a variable with the reverse index of the snapshots lenght, here is an example:

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('news').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading...');
        int reverseIndex = snapshot.data.documents.length;
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              reverseIndex -=1;
              return _buildItems(context, snapshot.data.documents[reverseIndex]);
            });
      }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind what comes first in your list, ie at the top, are the items that are in the first positions of your array. If the case, you can invert the array.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);


  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  List<int> Items = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

  void _incrementItems() {
    setState(() {
      Items = List.from([9, 8, 7, 6])..addAll(Items);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: Items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return  Text(
"Item "+Items[index].toString());

      },
    ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementItems,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Problem is my data are coming from firestore and inside a StreamBuilder, dont know how to reverse it. Receiving data as DocumentSnapshot inside itembuilder of ListView.

Answer (score 0):

```
StoreConnector<_ViewModel, List<Message>>(
      converter: (store) {
        // check mark ,reverse data list
        if (isReverse) return store.state.dialogList;
        return store.state.dialogList.reversed.toList();
      },
      builder: (context, dialogs) {
        // Add a callback when UI render after. then change it direction;
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((t) {
          // check it's items could be scroll
          bool newMark = _listViewController.position.maxScrollExtent > 0;
          if (isReverse != newMark) { // need 
            isReverse = newMark;  // rebuild listview
            setState(() {});
          }
        });

        return ListView.builder(
          reverse: isReverse, // if it has less data, it will false now;
          controller: _listViewController,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => _bubbleItem(context, dialogs[index], index),
          itemCount: dialogs.length,
        );
      },
    )
```